# relocation truncated to fit error : R_X86_64_32 against symbol

Tags: compiler-errors, jvm, java-native-interface, g++

I'm testing a simple example of jni (on windows 7) by calling java functions in a c++ main.

I read that "relocation truncated to fit" error is due to a large project (not the case : just a main and a compiled java class named Sample with a static method intMethod(int)), linking object files in a different order (i only have one object file), or an expansive mapping scheme ... [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486116/what-does-this-gcc-error-relocation-truncated-to-fit-mean)

I use the following compiling command line:
`g++ -D __int64="long long" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\include\win32" -L"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\lib" -o sample sample.cpp -ljvm`

and my main function:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <cstring>
#ifdef _WIN32
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ';'
#else
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ':'
#endif

int main()
{
   JavaVMOption options[1];
   JNIEnv *env;
   JavaVM *jvm;
   JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
   long status;
   jclass cls;
   jmethodID mid;
   jint square;
   jboolean no;
   options[0].optionString ="-Djava.class.path=.";

   //memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;
   vm_args.options = options;

   status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
   cls = env->FindClass("Sample");
   mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "intMethod", "(I)I");
   if(mid !=0)
    {  square = env->CallStaticIntMethod(cls, mid);
       printf("Result of intMethod: %d\n", square);
    }
   jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
   return 0;
}
```

The error is the following:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\lib/jvm.lib(jvm.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol  __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM defined in section .idata$5 in  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\lib/jvm.lib(jvm.dll.b)
>
> error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can't seem to find a good answer anywhere about how to handle this error methodically!

---

-> Solution:
Add -L"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\bin\server" in compilation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this GCC error "... relocation truncated to fit..." mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486116/what-does-this-gcc-error-relocation-truncated-to-fit-mean)

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the solution edited into the question, the linker command line should include `-L/path/to/jre/bin/server` (which contains `jvm.dll`). It should NOT contain `-L/path/to/jdk/lib` (which contains `jvm.lib`).

I'm not familiar with conventional Windows development so I can't explain what's going on here. I assume the questioner was working on Cygwin like me.

Note that what you run the program, `/path/to/jre/bin/server` must also be on your `PATH` (serving the same function as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

The truncation is referring to the stored relocation offset, not the symbol's label.  I believe your solution might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486116/what-does-this-gcc-error-relocation-truncated-to-fit-mean).

Comment: If you think an answer from the linked question answers this question, flag it as a duplicate.