# How to resolve "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `xmlStrcmp'"

Tags: c++, libxml2

I'm trying to use the libxml2 library in C++, but I get some errors which I do not know how to solve. My code is a basic example of the library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

void
parseStory (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {

    xmlChar *key;
    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"keyword"))) {
            key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
            printf("keyword: %s\n", key);
            xmlFree(key);
        }
    cur = cur->next;
    }
    return;
}

static void
parseDoc(char *docname) {

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr cur;

    doc = xmlParseFile(docname);

    if (doc == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
        return;
    }

    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    if (cur == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"empty document\n");
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        return;
    }

    if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "story")) {
        fprintf(stderr,"document of the wrong type, root node != story");
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        return;
    }

    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"storyinfo"))){
            parseStory (doc, cur);
        }

    cur = cur->next;
    }

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char *docname;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s docname\n", argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }

    docname = argv[1];
    parseDoc (docname);

    return (1);
}
```

And I get these errors while building the project.

> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:26:
>   undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:26:(.text+0x36):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlStrcmp'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:27:
>   undefined reference to `xmlNodeListGetString'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:27:(.text+0x59):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlNodeListGetString'
>
> build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o: In function
>   `parseDoc':
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:42:
>   undefined reference to`xmlParseFile'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:42:(.text+0xad):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlParseFile'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:49:
>   undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:49:(.text+0xec):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlDocGetRootElement'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:53:
>   undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:53:(.text+0x126):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlFreeDoc'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:57:
>   undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:57:(.text+0x142):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlStrcmp'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:59:
>   undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:59:(.text+0x17a):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlFreeDoc'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:65:
>   undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:65:(.text+0x1a6):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlStrcmp'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:72:
>   undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/robin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml/main.cpp:72:(.text+0x1d9):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `xmlFreeDoc'
>
> build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.xmlFree[.refptr.xmlFree]+0x0):
>   undefined reference to `xmlFree'

I've read this post [What does this GCC error "... relocation truncated to fit..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486116/what-does-this-gcc-error-relocation-truncated-to-fit-mean), but I have no clue how to solve my problem. My IDE is Netbeans 8.2 with Cygwin64 on a Windows 10 64 bit machine. I've included *libxml2-2.9.3-win32-x86_64.7z* and *iconv-1.14-win32-x86_64.7z*. I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this GCC error "... relocation truncated to fit..." mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486116/what-does-this-gcc-error-relocation-truncated-to-fit-mean)

Comment: As I have written, I read the post, but found no solution for my problem.

Comment: Hi @rpanske! Did you find a solution to this problem now? I am compiling C++ code with SQLite and Python that used to work fine in Mac in Windows using Netbeans IDE and Cygwin compiler. I am getting same error

Answer (score 2):

How did you install the library ?

I came across the same problem a few days ago with [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), and after hours and hours of Googling and digging every corner of the web to find a solution (because I'm still a newbit), I finally found it.

The solution that worked for me might not work for you, but it still worth it to give it a try, following these steps:

- Try to build your library into a static one instead of including it (Google will help you with this but it's as easy as `./configure` and `make`)
- Make sure the program can use the library without including it (`-v` flag can help)
- Add a compiler option `-llibname` (for example `-llibxml`). This option [Search the library named libname when linking.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC16)
- Try to compile and run the program as usual.

Goodluck !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Netbeans IDE for your C++ project. I faced similar issue and I solved it by

```
Right clicking on Project ==> Properties ==> Linker ==> Compilation Line ==> Additional Options ==> -llibxml
```

When I was using Mac OS, I had -llibxml under

```
C++ compiler ==> Compilation Line ==> Additional Options
```

In Mac OS that worked but NOT in Windows. As Daniel D. suggested, since --llibxml must be at end of execution command. placing it in Linker helped me